# ImageView on snackbar in Android not taking ṁinimum width

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-custom-view, snackbar

I am trying to launch a `snackbar`with a close icon to dismiss it at the end. This is my custom `snackbar`built with some changes over the default `snackbar`. It's working fine in landscape mode when there is enough space on the device to show the text and icons.

[image]

But in portrait mode, through layout inspector I can see that the view is there on the screen. But it's not taking the minimum width that it should take. Although in the `XML` file, I have defined the minimum height and width it should take.

[image]

What could be the possible reason for this and how can I fix it?

My layout is `LinearLayout`

And my xml file for the layout is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<view
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    class="com.example.testtransitentviews.CustomSnackbarContentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="48dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/snackbar_image"
        android:src="@drawable/pw_diamond"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:minHeight="24dp"
        android:minWidth="24dp"
        app:tint="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/snackbar_text"
        style="?attr/snackbarTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/color_snackbar_text" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/snackbar_action_image"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="24dp"
        android:minWidth="24dp"
        android:contentDescription="Close"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"/>
</view>
```

This is my class `CustomSnackbarContentLayout` which is extending `LinearLayout`

```
public class CustomSnackbarContentLayout extends LinearLayout implements ContentViewCallback {
    private ImageView iconImageView;
    private TextView messageView;
    private ImageView closeActionView;


    public CustomSnackbarContentLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomSnackbarContentLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        iconImageView = findViewById(R.id.snackbar_image);
        messageView = findViewById(R.id.snackbar_text);
        closeActionView = findViewById(R.id.snackbar_action_image);
    }

    public ImageView getIconImageView() {
        return iconImageView;
    }

    public TextView getMessageView() {
        return messageView;
    }

    public ImageView getCloseActionView() {
        return closeActionView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }


    @Override
    public void animateContentIn(int delay, int duration) {
        messageView.setAlpha(0f);
        messageView.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(duration).setStartDelay(delay).start();

        if (closeActionView.getVisibility() == VISIBLE) {
            closeActionView.setAlpha(0f);
            closeActionView.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(duration).setStartDelay(delay).start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void animateContentOut(int delay, int duration) {
        messageView.setAlpha(1f);
        messageView.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(duration).setStartDelay(delay).start();

        if (closeActionView.getVisibility() == VISIBLE) {
            closeActionView.setAlpha(1f);
            closeActionView.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(duration).setStartDelay(delay).start();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `XML` file for the drawable "close" button that I am using.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"><path
    android:pathData="M19,6.4L17.6,5L12,10.6L6.4,5L5,6.4l5.6,5.6L5,17.6L6.4,19l5.6,-5.6l5.6,5.6l1.4,-1.4L13.4,12L19,6.4z"
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"/>
</vector>
```

As per this also, even if I give wrap content as attribute to my `ImageView`, it should take at least 24dp height and width.

If you are able to figure out why my close button on `snackbar` is not taking the required min width, then please answer. It will be a great help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hardcode the horizontal weight of the `TextView` to allow the close button to show:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/snackbar_text"
    style="?attr/snackbarTextViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ..../>
```